# Scala Reflection of Nested List

Tags: list, scala, reflection, nested

I'm having some trouble with nested Lists and Scala reflection.

How can I introspect a case class field of type `List[List[something]]`?

Some code here.  It's stripped--in real life it builds static data about a reflected class.  The interesting part is `inspectField`.

```
import reflect.runtime.currentMirror
import reflect.runtime.universe._

case class Pet(val name: String, val legs: Int)
case class ListList2(val name: String, val stuff: List[List[Pet]])

object Boom extends App {
    // Introspect class and find all its members (constructor fields)
    val symbol = currentMirror.classSymbol(Class.forName("com.br.ListList2"))
    val constructor = symbol.toType.members.collectFirst {
        case method: MethodSymbol if method.isPrimaryConstructor && method.isPublic && !method.paramss.isEmpty && !method.paramss.head.isEmpty => method
    }.getOrElse( throw new IllegalArgumentException("Case class must have at least 1 public constructor having more than 1 parameters."))

    // Loop through each field
    constructor.paramss.head.map( c => inspectField(c) )

    private def inspectField[T]( sym:Symbol ) : String = {      
        val cname = sym.name.toString
        println("Field: "+cname)
        val cType = sym.typeSignature
        if( cType.typeSymbol.fullName.toString == "scala.collection.immutable.List" ) {
            println("C: "+cType)
            val subtype = cType.asInstanceOf[TypeRef].args(0)  // Goes boom here on first recursive call
            println("Sub:"+subtype)
            inspectField(subtype.typeSymbol)
        }
        "Hi"
    }
}
```

My case class specifies a field of type `List[List[Animal]]`.  I expect my `inspectField` code to be called recursively.  First time through no problem. It prints:

```
Field: name
Field: stuff
C: scala.List[scala.List[com.br.Pet]]
Sub:scala.List[com.br.Pet]
```

So far that's what I expect.  Now on the recursive call to `inspectField` this time passing the `subtype` of the first call `(List[Pet])`.  I expected output like this:

```
Field: stuff
C: scala.List[com.br.Pet]
Sub:com.br.Pet
```

Instead this goes boom with an error where noted:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: scala.reflect.internal.Types$PolyType cannot be cast to scala.reflect.api.Types$TypeRefApi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This snippet shows matching to pull apart the type, and the two calls to showType show what you're doing and what you intend.

```
val cType = sym.typeSignature
def showType(t: Type): Unit = {
  if( t.typeSymbol.fullName.toString == "scala.collection.immutable.List" ) {
    t match {
      case PolyType(typeParams, resultType) =>
        println(s"poly $typeParams, $resultType")
      case TypeRef(pre, sym, args) =>
        println(s"typeref $pre, $sym, $args")
        val subtype = args(0)
        println("Sub:"+subtype)
        showType(subtype.typeSymbol.typeSignature)
        showType(subtype)
    }
  }
}
showType(cType)
```